# Metro ui: how to play audio stream in background mode

Tags: windows-8

I am implementing audio player that will should be able play real time PCM stream while application goes to background mode. All solutions (XAudio2, IAudioClient2) I have tried so far stop playback as soon as app goes into background.
Any help is appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i am sure this should be possible.. it is in WP7 so don't see why Win8 would be impossible. quick search yields http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx which has a link to Build (yes Build) to Background audio.

Here's a link to WinRT c# sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-in-WinRT-344bcf4d

Another one here by which shows you how easy it is to configure Media Element to do background audio
http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/metro-background-audio-c-consumer-preview/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a MediaElement with the AudioCategory=BackgroundCapable property. It needs to be instantiated on a XAML page.

Apply this style to your root frame:

```
<Style  x:Key="RootFrameStyle" TargetType="Frame">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame">
                <Grid>
                    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="True"  />
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then you can play media like this:

```
var rootGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Window.Current.Content, 0);    
var mediaElement = (MediaElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootGrid, 0);

mediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///relative/path/to/file.mp3");
```

You then need to declare your app capable of background audio in the app manifest.

Full explanation on my blog here: http://rikk.it/2012/10/background-audio-in-a-metro-c-sharp-app/

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions but in my case I need write renderer by myself. I writed renderer already by using SharpDX XAudio2(Which is wrapper for directx) Is there any way to playback audio in background using these libraries? Because I'm playing RAW PCM audio in my application.

Comment: Ah, I see. You will still need to use the MediaElement for background audio, but instead of the C# above you can use mediaElement.SetSource() which allows you to assign a RandomAccessStream instead of a file Uri.